# What is the violin soundtrack that plays in episode 47 when Gon receives Ging's tape?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

What is the soundtrack (probably violin) that plays in episode 47 of Hunter x Hunter 1999 when Gon receives Ging's tape?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the music that is playing in the background while the tape recording of his father is being played then it's not a violin but a harmonica.

It is the harmonica version of the song "Ohayou" (Composed by Keno) which is part of the soundtrack in the first anime adaptation of Hunter x Hunter.

You can listen to it on [youtube](https://youtu.be/FFDzHLeSFc8?t=10)